# How do I bind the Header of a TextBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In windows phone 8.1, I can bind the text in a textbox to a string resource in my Resources.resw.

How do I do the same thing for the Header="My Header" tag?

i.e. bind the Header text to another string resource in Resources.resw

```
<TextBox Header="My Header" Text="{Binding textboxtext}" x:Name="TextBox"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way you Bind the Text field.

```
<TextBox Header="{Binding myBinding}" Text="{Binding textboxtext}" x:Name="TextBox"/>
```

If you want to point it to a Resource then

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="myTextBoxHeader">this is a textbox header</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding textboxtest}"
    Header="{StaticResource myTextBoxHeader}"></TextBox>
```

[image]

If you pointing to a **.resw file** then in most cases you will need a `x:Uid` like this

```
<TextBox x:Uid="MyLocalizeTextBox"></TextBox>
```

Then you need to edit the strings for the stuff you want to display, in this case your Header + Text

[image]

Look at the highlighted section very carefully, you see the pattern?  It won't show up on the designer and will show up when you deploy [See Image Below]

[image]

---

So by now you may be wondering if you combine both methods? (one to show in the designer and one to show while deploy because you're localizing).  This is actually the prefer method.

2 in 1 (Both methods)

```
<TextBox x:Uid="MyLocalizeTextBox"
    Text="{Binding textboxtest}" Header="{StaticResource myBinding}"></TextBox>
```

During design time it will use your local resouces, when deploy it will use the resources in the resw file.

Comment: If I use the second line, it says the resource cannot be resolved. I tried exactly the same format for a textblock. The textblock can display the string while the textbox header cannot display the string. Is there a special extension in the Resources.resw file for this header string?

Comment: @user776914 Why do you have a Resources.resw file?  Are you localizing your app?  If not, then why doesn't that TextBox have a `x:Uid`?

Comment: @user776914 See updated solution.  This is somewhat advance stuff.. I got a feeling you just created a project from a default template and it is very confusing, I would suggest not using any databound template until you a lot of experiences with the environment.

Comment: Well, I thought it would be good practice to put all the strings in the resource file? Your method looks good, one for design time and one for runtime. Shall implement it, thanks!

Comment: by the way, the answer that I needed was that I needed to set the x:Uid to "name" and the name in the resource file to "name.header". Didn't know that these can be used this way..

Comment: @user776914 Think it was meant for localization meaning you want to support multiple languages.  Otherwise, I think it is very cumbersome to use.